# Can I publish a bot, created using bot framework .NET core template, using bot composer

Tags: botframework, bots

I have created a bot using Template in VS 2019. I Can deploy it using Azure CLI and Directly publishing from Visual Studio to Azure. I just want to know can i deploy it using Bot framework composer or not. As I am trying to open a bot using composer but it is not letting me open it.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the bot using a template from VS, then you cannot publish from Composer. Bots created outside of Composer are not compatible and therefore you will not be able to open it, nor publish it.